# Link a page from admin to a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin, page-template

I created a custom taxonomy with the following code in functions.php (child theme) :

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_location_taxonomy' );

    function create_location_taxonomy() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                           => 'Locations',
            'singular_name'                  => 'Locations',
            'search_items'                   => 'Search Location',
            'all_items'                      => 'All Locations',
            'edit_item'                      => 'Edit Location',
            'update_item'                    => 'Update Location',
            'add_new_item'                   => 'Add New Location',
            'new_item_name'                  => 'New Location Name',
            'menu_name'                      => 'Location',
            'view_item'                      => 'View Location',
            'popular_items'                  => 'Popular Locations',
            'separate_items_with_commas'     => 'Separate locations with commas',
            'add_or_remove_items'            => 'Add or remove location',
            'choose_from_most_used'          => 'Choose from the most used location',
            'not_found'                      => 'No location found'
        );

        register_taxonomy(
            'Location',
            'post',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Location' ),
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                'show_tagcloud' => false,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'locations'
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

This allows me to add a location to each of my posts and in the admin page, under post, I see "Location" under "Tags" where I can manage them.

I already know how to make a list of my custom taxonomy and when I click on a custom taxonomy link (e.g. http://example.com/locations/abc), I get to a page that displays all posts with the according custom taxonomy.

Now I am trying to do the following : I want to design this page (the ones that displays all posts) under my wordpress admin according to a specific template, so that the posts of a specific custom taxonomy are displayed the way defined by the template of the page in my admin.

I have no idea if that is possible and if so, how to do it...but I need the page to be done via the wordpress admin (and not only by creating a taxonomy-location.php page with my code in it, since the template of the page is generated via the admin wordpress in fact).

Thanks for any help!

EDIT : 
tl;dr is it possible to create a new page (e.g. Locations with slug being 'locations'), **from admin panel**, that will be used for custom taxonomy. Hence when accessing the page http://example.com/locations/abc, I get all posts with custom taxonomy abc ?

Answer (score 0):

While WP will helpfully construct many of admin pages for you, you can just as easily create your own from scratch.

[`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) allows you to register arbitrary admin page and have full control over it.

Comment: I corrected my initial post to add a bit of clarification. I am not trying to add a page in my admin in the way you are saying, I am trying to use a page designed under the "Pages" in the menu, that will be the template used to display the posts of a specific custom taxonomy

Comment: I am not following the distinction you are making. You can the page in admin anywhere and how it works is up to you.

Comment: I am not trying to add a menu page, or admin page. I am trying to use a page designed in the admin via Visual Composer, to display the posts of a custom taxonomy in a certain way. Currently, these posts are displayed like a regular blog (i.e. one after the other), whereas if I design it via the Visual Composer I can have my posts displayed as a grid. I want to do it via the admin because the code will be generated via Visual Composer.

Comment: _...designed in the admin via Visual Composer..._ aaaand you are on your own from this point, no remote idea how that works, sorry. :)

Comment: The Visual Composer detail is not really important. The question itself is : how to display posts that belong to the custom taxonomy, on a page (archive type I would say) that is created from the admin ?